# AWS Lambda and HDF5

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, hdf5

I'd like to work with a HDF5 file stored in AWS S3. My initial idea was to build a Lambda function that could pull that file, append data to the table, then upload the file back to S3 with python.

However, PyTables (and h5py) require libhdf5-dev. Is there a method for getting the HDF5 driver into the execution environment? Or does this mean that HDF5 is simply not usable in the AWS Lambda space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda functions run in [64 bit Amazon Linux containers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html). First, compile your python program to a statically linked executable on the version of Amazon Linux linked above. Second, create a Node.js lambda function and [fork a child process](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/) that launches your python program. By forking a new process, Lambda functions support running arbitrary code.